# ng-view contents reevaluated for the same route

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have the following problem: the application has a static top panel which contains a horizontal main menu. The central area contains ng-view which changes accordingly to the selection of the main menu item. In the ng-view, for some of the main menu items, we want to display another navigation panel with a vertical sub-menu and a detail panel. The detail panel is another ng-view and changes accordingly to the selection of the sub-menu item.

E.g. for recipe book application if want to have some main menu items like: home, recipes, gallery, contact, and for recipes I have e.g. list of recipes

Lines represent ng-views:

```
     MAIN MENU
---------------------------
|          --------------- | 
| SUB-MENU | DETAIL PANEL| |
|          |             | |
|          |_____________| |
|__________________________|



Routes:
    /home (template home.html)
    /recipes (template recipes.html with a sub-menu and <ng-view> inside)
        /:recipe (view_recipe.html)
```

What I want to achieve is an animation effect on the sub-menu when going between different recipes. The problem is that the sub-menu is rendered from scratch when changing a recipe. This is strange, as it does not need to change, because the part of the url responsible for picking up recipes.html does not change. In AngularJS, as expected, the sub-menu is not rendered again. Is this a bug in AngularDart, or the expected behavior?

Another difficulty I struggle with is how to find active element in the sub-menu. I try to use RouteProvider in the sub-menu controller, however the route does not contain recipeId. How can this be solved?